# Writing compound editors in handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, handsontable

In this example you can cancompound cell editors driving multiple fields from one cell.
http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example3a-compound-editors.html

I am wondering if ti is possible to make it also for [jquery-handsontable](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable).

Any hints how to make it by using handsontable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. That is a little bit challenging but it is surely doable.

Just take a look at the source of CheckboxEditor and CheckboxRenderer to see how to insert a `<input>` editor inside a cell:

- https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/blob/master/src/editors/checkboxEditor.js
- https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/blob/master/src/renderers/checkboxRenderer.js

Double that and change input type to `text` and you will have a compund text editor.

That said, I am not big fan of this concept because it breaks standard flow of working with a spreadsheet. It would be hard to maintain the current keyboard experience. Normally, you expect that the effect of pressing enter or keyboard arrows on a cell would be simmilar as in Excel.